# OSX Monterey: windows don't stay on second screen after sleep

Tags: macos, display, multiple-monitors, sleep

I noticed that after installing Monterey (v12.4, MacBookPro M1 2020) many app windows (such as Safari) would be relocated from the secondary display monitor to the main MacBook display, after the displays turned off.
I managed to resolve this issue by going to "System Preferences --> Battery --> Power Adapter" and selecting "Prevent your Mac from automatically sleeping when display is off".

What I'd like to know is if there is a better solution to this issue, as I'd prefer not to have to unselect this option every night (when I want my Mac to sleep) or when I'm on battery power, or even just closing the MacBook for transport.

Comment: Does the display have any button that will force it to wake? If so, do that before waking the Mac. This is a common issue with many computers. The screen doesn't wake fast enough, so the computer thinks it's been disconnected - for just long enough to pull all the windows back to the Primary - then it finds it, but it's too late.

Comment: @Tetsujin that is great insight, thank you! I played around with it and eventually had to turn off the "Monitor Sleep" function. It's connected via HDMI so it still goes dark (into Standby Mode) when the Mac goes to sleep but retains all the windows when it gets the signal back.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Tesujin for the insight. Turns out turning Sleep Mode off on the monitor wasn't necessary. The monitor is connected to a hub via HDMI. The wireless USB mouse is connected to that same hub. If I wake the computer using the mouse, I get the relocation issue. If I wake the computer by pressing a key on the keyboard...the windows remain in place.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, too.  I solved it by selecting the external display as the "Primary display" in settings.  Now they reopen on the bigger screen every time.

Comment: Kind of half works. Now I get the windows arranged in the bigger display, but then, my MacBook's display now loses the windows... but that's much better since I only have vscode there.

Comment: yeah, it's hit or miss for me...more often miss. We're finally getting Linux laptops soon, so I will be able to get rid of this piece of junk. The hardware is awesome! The OS can bite me. Those guys can't code their way out of a paper bag.

Answer (score 2):

FTR, I've had this issue with OSX for a few years now. I freaking hate OSX but it's the best my company can offer for now until I can get Linux in here. At any rate, I have the same problem. I have two 4K TV vertically mounted. It doesn't matter what sequence I use for waking my machine, OSX almost *always* loses the location of the windows OR it completely forgets my display settings and I have to re-config my entire set up. I really hate OSX.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this behavior in my case: I have two LG 4k screens. When at home, the lit of my mac is closed. But OSX cannot distinguish when waking-up on which display which window should (re-) appear. This is because the two LG 4k screens have the same name. Both are called LG Ultra HD.